# Electrum Merchant Crashing

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am trying to get electrum merchant running, and it keeps crashing on me. I have tried using several different versions of python3; (python3.6.0, 3.6.8, and 3.7), but I keep getting this same error when I try to run it:

```
python3.6 -m electrum-merchant
[2019-06-01 02:34:15,120] [INFO] Downloading and installing files into request directory
[2019-06-01 02:34:15,121] [INFO] copying index.html from flavour simple
[2019-06-01 02:34:15,123] [INFO] Downloading jquery
[2019-06-01 02:34:15,125] [DEBUG] GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jquery/latest
[2019-06-01 02:34:16,221] [INFO] Downloaded jquery@3.4.1
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/npmdownloader/npmclient.py:19: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession.close' was never awaited # 
  self._session.close()
E | asyncio | Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fee5ec82048>
E | asyncio | Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fee5e95f108>, 91761.087309849)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7fee5ec820b8>
[2019-06-01 02:34:16,260] [INFO] Downloading qrcodejs
[2019-06-01 02:34:16,260] [DEBUG] GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qrcodejs/latest
[2019-06-01 02:34:17,201] [INFO] Downloaded qrcodejs@1.0.0
[2019-06-01 02:34:18,351] [INFO] Processing: /var/www/html/payment/static/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.tgz into /var/www/html/payment/static/jquery
[2019-06-01 02:34:18,472] [INFO] Deleting /var/www/html/payment/static/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.tgz
[2019-06-01 02:34:25,008] [INFO] Processing: /var/www/html/payment/static/qrcodejs/qrcodejs-1.0.0.tgz into /var/www/html/payment/static/qrcodejs
[2019-06-01 02:34:25,021] [INFO] Deleting /var/www/html/payment/static/qrcodejs/qrcodejs-1.0.0.tgz
[2019-06-01 02:34:33,232] [INFO] Downloaded Jquery-UI.
[2019-06-01 02:34:33,459] [INFO] Downloaded Jquery-UI 3.x fix.
[2019-06-01 02:34:35,413] [INFO] Downloaded Jquery-UI themes.
[2019-06-01 02:34:35,413] [INFO] Finished.
E | asyncio | Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fee5e9b5e80>
E | asyncio | Unclosed connector
```

I think the issue is with [npmdownloader](https://github.com/ozelentok/NpmDownloader), at least I know that warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/npmdownloader/npmclient.py:19: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession.close' was never awaited #
```

But I am not sure because it appears to download those packages just fine. (See [this thread](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2800))

I also tried manually installing with 
    $ python3.6 setup.py build
    $ python3.6 setup.py install

But still have this problem. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I have configured everything correctly as per the [instructions](http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/merchant.html):

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, these errors do not matter. Electrum-merchant simply configures electrum so that you can crate payment requests using the `electrum` command:

```
electrum addrequest 3.14 -m "This is how we create payment requests!"
{
   "URI": "bitcoin:1MP49h5fbfLXiFpomsXeqJHGHUfNf3mCo4?amount=3.14&r=https://example.com/payment/7c2888541a",
   "address": "1MP49h5fbfLXiFpomsXeqJHGHUfNf3mCo4",
   "amount": 314000000,
   "amount (BTC)": "3.14",
   "exp": 3600,
   "id": "7c2888541a",
   "index_url": "https://example.com/payment/index.html?id=7c2888541a",
   "memo": "this is a test",
   "request_url": "https://example.com/payment/7c2888541a",
   "status": "Pending",
   "time": 1450175741
}
```

Those errors can safely be ignored.